# Button can't be seen when created

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton

I have a UIButton in my `viewController`, everything worked fine until I change some code of its destination view controller, now it can't be seen, when I touch it, it gives me a crash.

- I checked in its view controller, it's created, it's not transparent, and not hidden.
- I'm using a custom animation to transition from this button to `destinationViewController`
- The `destinationViewController`is shrieked and hidden at the place of the button, otherwise it has nothing to do with `viewController`
- I have 3 constraints to the button: aspect ratio = 1 : 1, bottom = bottom layout guide + 34, centerX

  ```
  @IBOutlet weak var calculateButton: UIButton!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      calculateButton.isEnabled = false
      calculateButton.layer.cornerRadius = calculateButton.frame.size.width / 2
  }

  func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
      if itemCountTextField.text != "" {
          calculateButton.isEnabled = true
      } else {
          calculateButton.isEnabled = false
      }
      textField.resignFirstResponder()
      return true
  }


  func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

      transtion.transitionMode = .dismiss
      transtion.startingPoint = calculateButton.center
      transtion.circleColor = calculateButton.backgroundColor!

      return transtion
  }

  func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

      transtion.transitionMode = .present
      transtion.startingPoint = calculateButton.center
      transtion.circleColor = calculateButton.backgroundColor!

      return transtion
  }
  ```

Why is it disappeared?

Comment: Can you add the button code please

Comment: You have probably not added constraints to it and therefore it´s hidden. Control your constraints.

Comment: @RashwanL confirmed, not the problem of constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody for answering. @RashwanL is right, we should controller our constraints when designing with storyboard.

I put `print(calculateButton.frame.size.width)` in `viewDidLoad()`, and I found the size of the button is 1000. Then I checked the constraints of the button, and tried to simply it, now it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that until `viewDidAppear` is called, layout is not complete.  (XCode8)   Therefor when `calculateButton.layer.cornerRadius = calculateButton.frame.size.width / 2` 
is called in `viewDidLoad` the frame size of calculateButton might not be correct and you might end up with a too big a corner radius, which ends up in an invisible image after viewDidAppear.

Try adding `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` before setting the cornerRadius or calling the code in `viewDidAppear`.

Also, you say you have 3 constraints:

> I have 3 constraints to the button: aspect ratio = 1 : 1, bottom =
>   bottom layout guide + 34, centerX

This is not enough to successfully specify the layout of the button.  You need to specify either the width or height as well.  Now a height and width of 0 pixels is totally valid as long as width == height.